# Syntax error when calling a function with parameters in slim template

Tags: html, ruby, templates, syntax, slim-lang

I have a slim template where I call a function like so:

```
textarea.form-control value = @function(parameter)
```

However I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

Its strange that it does not like the '(" character because that's how I would imagine we would call functions with arguments from a template. What am I doing wrong and how can I call a function with an argument from a slim template. Apologies if this is a basic question, I am very new to slim and ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need the `@`:

```
textarea.form-control value = function(parameter)
```

As long as `function` and `parameter` are defined then this should work.

You may be confusing Ruby attributes (which use `@`) with functions/methods (which don’t). If you want to pass an attribute as the parameter, then you need the `@` in front of its name:

```
textarea.form-control value = function(@attribute)
```